# Where goes firebase custom logs

Tags: firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

Can't find where Firebase custom logs are send.
Firebase console, only shows fatal an non fatal errors.
Firebase documentation doesnt's specify, at least, that i am aware of.

Here an example of Firebase custom logs use, for clarification.

```
FirebaseCrash.log("Wrong path");
```

**Update:**
 For those who come after don't wast mutch time on this. I try the following code and was added to firebase console besides the exceptions. I am using Android platform, firease version "10.0.1".

```
   try {
        throw  new Exception("Try 1");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(6,TAG,"test 1");
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(4,TAG,"test 1 Info");
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(6,"whatever place","test Error 1");
        FirebaseCrash.report(ex);
    }

    try {
        throw  new Exception("Try 2");
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(6,TAG,"test 2");
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(4,TAG,"test 2 Info");
        FirebaseCrash.logcat(6,"whatever place","test Error 2");
    }
```

Comment: _Pass custom data as a string to `FIRCrashLog()` on iOS or `FirebaseCrash.log()` on Android, and you'll see the results in the Firebase console._

As metioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/?hl=en).

Comment: As i posted, it is not there, on the firebase console. Only get errors(exceptions), fatal and not fatal.

Answer (score 1):

Custom logging is meant as supplemental log statements for when fatal or non-fatal errors occur. They will not show up in the Firebase console outside of an error log.

Comment: That is what it looks like it, but for that there are other options, like logcat, and logcat is native. Can you support your statement?

Comment: Based on experience, that's just how these kinds of solutions work. Same with Crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see Crash Reporting log messages in *both* the device logs and the Firebase Console, use [FirebaseCrash.logcat()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/crash/FirebaseCrash.html#logcat(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).  Firebase.log() just logs messages in the console when a crash is collected.

Comment: it writes on logcat, but don't see it at firebase crash console, even if the level is 6 (Error).

Comment: That's not the way it's documented to work.  If you're absolutely certain this is not working, please file a bug report.  Please be sure you're looking at the correct crash - a single cluster can contain many of individual crashes that each have separate logs.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I just added the test code to the question. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: The first exception should be reported as a non-fatal exception.  The second one would not get reported at all, because you caught it, and didn't report it.

Comment: Also, you should be using the constants from Log, such as Log.ERROR.  It's not a good idea to use the plain numbers.

Comment: It's is reported as you say. but it miss the all log messages. Tks for the tip.